'R' load library from local directory for debugging
I have found a bug in a library (seqinr), and would like to fix it. I have downloaded the latest version from GitHub, so I have the code in a local directory. How to I tell R to use the library in my local directory, instead of the system library directory?

You can use devtools::install() to install your local version, then library(seqinr) will load your own version.

You can point to a specific directory to load from in the library call with the lib.loc argument like so:
library("yourLibrary", lib.loc = "/the/path/to/directory/R/library/4.3")
